# Rename the newly created sheet based on active cell in Sheet1

Tags: excel, rename, vba

I am newbie at VBA and have a problem to solve, which for you will be more than simple, I am sure. Here is the problem:

I have table with company names in column A. What I want is to select cell with company name, click the button which will run a macro creating new sheet based on template, and rename the newly created sheet with name of the selected cell in Sheet1 (company name).

The macro generally works, I have only problem with renaming it. Your help will be greatly appriciated. Also any comments on my code in general will be very useful. Here is the code:

```
Sub NewSheet()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim activeWB As Workbook
Dim FilePath As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
wb.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=activeWB.Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.Count)
activeWB.Activate

ActiveSheet.Name = Worksheets("Arkusz1").ActiveCell.Value

wb.Close False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code opens a workbook. Do you want to create a new sheet in the workbook that has the selected cell or do you want to open a workbook and create a new sheet in the other workbook??

Comment: Side Note: Avoid using `On Error Resume Next` which is bad practice because it just mutes errors but does not handle them. Instead use a proper [Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/5411/error-handling).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reaction. Well, in my workbook the template opens as a new sheet, so I thought that it is a worksheet. I want to have it the same workbook where selected cell is, opening as a new sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use the `ActiveCell`, you can use something like the code below:

```
Dim ShtName As String
ShtName = ActiveCell.Value2 ' <-- save the value of the ActiveCell

Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
wb.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=activeWB.Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.Count)

' rename the sheet
activeWB.Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.Count).Name = ShtName
```

Comment: That worked exactly as I wanted! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You've copied the new worksheet to the end, so you can get hold of the last worksheet like so:

```
Set activeWB = ActiveWorkbook
' You copied sheet 1
wb.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=activeWB.Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.Count)
' New sheet is last sheet
Dim sh As WorkSheet
Set sh = activeWB.Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.Count)
' Rename sheet
sh.Name = activeWB.Sheets("Arkusz1").ActiveCell.Value
```

Please note, relying on selections and active cells/sheets/workbooks is *risky*, and can create hard-to-diagnose errors. Try and use cell addresses instead of active cells.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I will keep it in mind as I will be learning VBA. As to your answer I can't get it working, not sure why. Probably I did something wrong. Fortunately answer from Shai Rado worked perfectly.

Comment: Ah glad your problem was resolved, for reference this question's answer has some great pointers for avoiding `Select` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Comment: It really has. Thanks a lot!